# Show that $T$ is continuous in $C([a,a+h], [\gamma - R,\gamma+R])$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose that $\Phi$ is a real valued continuous function on $[a,a+h] \times [\gamma - R,\gamma + R]$ where $h > 0$, $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$, and $R > 0$. Define $T:C([a,a+h], [\gamma - R,\gamma+R]) \to C[a,a+h]$ by $$TF(x) = \gamma + \int_a^x \Phi(t,F(t)) \, dt.$$

I want to show that $T$ is continuous on $C([a,a+h], [\gamma - R,\gamma+R])$.

**My attempt:** Suppose $(F_n)$ is a sequence in $C([a,a+h], [\gamma - R,\gamma+R])$ that converges to $F$, then $$|TF_n(x)-TF(x)| =\left|\int_a^x \Phi(t,F_n(t)) - \Phi(t,F(t)) \, dt \right| \leq \int_a^x \left|\Phi(t,F_n(t))- \Phi(t,F(t)) \right| \, dt.$$

This is where I'm stuck. Is there any hint or suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Use the hypothesis $\Phi$ is continous to go one step further in the integral

Answer (score 1):

$|TF_n(x)-TF(X)| \leq \int_a^h \left|\Phi(t,F_n(t))- \Phi(t,F(t)) \right| dt$. Given $\epsilon >0$ choose $\delta >0$ such that $|\Phi (t,x)-\Phi(t,y)|  <\epsilon $ for $|x-y|<\delta$. This is possible because $\Phi$ is uniformly continuous. Now choose $n_o0$ such that $|F_n(t)-F(t)| <\delta$ for all $t$ if $n \geq n_0$. We now get $|TF_n(x)-TF(x)| <\epsilon (h-a)$ for all $t$ is $n \geq n_0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!